# Visual Studio Code C++, I would like to run the output in a cmd

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I would like to run the output of the c++ code that I have made in a command prompt rather than the terminal.  Also, if I run an infinite loop, how would I terminate the current program given that I am in terminal? Still, can somebody help me run my codes in a cmd[command prompt] instead of terminal? I have been using code runner.

Comment: *I would like to run the output of the c++ code that I have made in a command prompt rather than the terminal.* It must be late. I don't understand what you mean by this. Do you mean to open a command prompt, cd to your working directory and run the program from there? As opposed to inside VS itself?

Comment: It's unclear... to me a "command prompt" and a "terminal" is the same thing. Do you mean you want to run your code _outside_ of VS Code? Meaning, you don't want to use the terminal at the bottom of the VS Code UI?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: "terminal" in the Visual Studio sense is the Output window in the IDE.  He wants to open a command prompt and run the program from there.

Comment: What keeps you from doing that? You need to explain your obstacle to make the question clear. (Also, please decide on a single question to ask or your question is too broad.)

Comment: _Also, if I run an infinite loop, how would I terminate the current program given that I am in terminal?_ Have you tried [Ctrl][C]? ;-)

Comment: Open cmd session > Navigate to the directory where you build your executable > start exe from there? 

Or in VSCode; Debug > Start without Debugging

I think, this is what you want, but not too sure to be honest.